# To search and get the jar from a path to execute

Tags: java, maven, jar, sap-ase

We are working on Java Maven project. We are dealing with database to get their schema. One of them is Sybase database, so we generate its ddl using DDLGen command line utility. To use ddlgen, I have imported these three jars in my code and added them into class-path in running jars:

- jconn4.jar
- DDLGen.jar
- dsparser.jar

After that, we have used following code to generate DDL:

```
String command = "java -cp \"myPath\\lib\\com\\jconn4\\4.0\\jconn4-4.0.jar;myPath\\lib\\com\\dsparser\\4.0\\dsparser-4.0.jar;myPath\\lib\\com\\DDLGen\\4.0\\DDLGen-4.0.jar\" com.sybase.ddlgen.DDLGenerator -UuserName -Ppassword -SconnectionString -DdatabaseName -OoutputFile";
        try {
            Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = run.exec(command);
            pr.waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {
           //errors
        }
```

This code  working fine when jars are found at path in their respective folders (hard-coded) : **myPath\lib\com**

On building the project, this structure will be changed, like all jar used in project will be put into path ***....myProject/repo/alljars***

Then ddlgen should have to be changed like :

```
String command = "java -cp \"repo\\jconn4-4.0.jar;repo\\dsparser-4.0.jar;repo\\DDLGen-4.0.jar\"
```

BUT this is not a correct solution to change the path every time, when code running using IDE and with build.

I just want an solution that these jar files should be searched into project path whether from IDE or build, then above given jars should be added into classpath in **-cp** command, then it should execute ddlgen.

Thus is there any way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Did you try exec-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems when your program is run the `jconn4-4.0.jar`, etc. are already in classpath.

In that case, you do not need to launch another copy of the jvm, you can instead simply execute the `Main` method of the class as follows:

```
com.sybase.ddlgen.DDLGenerator.Main(
    "-UuserName",  "-Ppassword",  "-SconnectionString",  "-DdatabaseName" "-OoutputFile")
```

As a bonus, you would also be able to catch any exceptions thrown, instead of having to parse the output from the other jvm.

Comment: Does renaming jar like jconn4.jar to jconn4-4.0.jar affect ddlegen command?

Comment: Thanks! but it won't generating the ddl using above suggestion.

Comment: I do not know the ddlgen command, but renaming it should not generally affect the behavior. Why won't it generate ddl when the method is invoked directly?